# Adding event to each picturbox I add to my form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have made an application that allows users to add custom items to a menu overlay using an ini file to save the items on the menu.

I have a class for reading and saving ini files in my project.

To read the items contained in the ini file, I have used a `for each` loop.
Here is my code to do this:

```
Dim newItem As New PictureBox
newItem.Image = Image.FromFile(item.GetKey("iconLocation").Value)
Me.Controls.Add(newItem)
newItem.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
newItem.Size = New Point(60, 60)
newItem.Location = New Point(QuickLaunchIcon.Location.X + distanceFromLaunchItem,
                             QuickLaunchIcon.Location.Y)
distanceFromLaunchItem = distanceFromLaunchItem + 72
doneItems.Add(item.Name)
```

As you can see, I declare a local variable named newItem. However, as the form adds multiple versions of this newItem, I cannot add a handler for each 'newItem' that can run a different sub so if I was to add a handler for newItem, all the instances of newItem would run the same sub on click. However, I would like each newItem to run a different sub on click.

Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT:
I have been told how to do this but now I have run into another problem. All the pictureboxes run the same sub but I cannot differentiate which picturebox is being clicked not... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Put an `If` condition...

Comment: What determines what code should each PictureBox run?  That code needs to be pre-written.

Comment: How do I add a handler as when I try `AddHandler newItem, AddressOf OnNewItemClicked` visual studio gives me 'newItem' is not an event of QuickLauncher.LaunchBar (name of my form) can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @rodit: `newItem.Click`, or perhaps `newItem.NewItemClicked` in your case.

Comment: @rodit: Is your problem resolved? Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @Neolisk I now have a different problem - please read the edit... Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Give each picture box a name. Then do an if or select case on `DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Name`.

Comment: @Neolisk I cannot give each picturebox a name as I have created them programatically and for them all to be different, I have had to use a local variable in the for statement (see code above). Is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: @Neolisk and when I use DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Name at the moment, the return is always nothing...

Comment: You need to find a way to differentiate between your picture boxes, whether it be `Name` or anything else. And yes, you need to give it a name, to be able to retrieve it later. It won't be assigned automatically for you.

Comment: @Neolisk How can I give it a name?

Comment: @Neolisk If I knew that would solve everything!

Comment: As simple as `newItem.Name = "123"`, but you probably have figured this already. Should I post something as an answer? :)

Comment: That would be great @Neolisk thanks much! Ill be sure to accept your answer as the answer! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each picture box can be assigned a `Name` like this:

```
newItem.Name = "SomeName"
```

In your event handler you can branch by `DirectCast(sender, PictureBox).Name`, choose either an `If`, or a `Select Case`, the latter is usually less code.

For a lot picture boxes, it's best to use a `Dictionary(Of String, PictureBox)` and `TryGetValue` in that. Regular `String` comparison done in sequence is very slow on big volumes of data.